# Outputting the cucumber junit report to specific xml file

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-junit

In my `cucumber.yml` file I gave following line of code to generate the junit report. The objective is to generate the junit report in file `report.xml` , however after the execution it is creating the folder with name `report.xml` and generating the report in file `TEST-Appllication-Feature.xml`

Please let us know how we can specify the file name in the Junit report.

```
p3: <%= standard_opts %> --tags @p3 --profile html_report  --profile junit_report
junit_report: --format junit  --out=report.xml
```

Comment: Please let us know in case anyone is aware of answer

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your plugin and you are good to go.

```
plugin = {"junit:target/cucumber-results.xml"}
```

This gives you a junit report.